# Uncaught Error: Module name "https" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, requirejs

This is the error that I'm getting-

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "https" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (require.js:1436)
    at requirejs (require.js:1797)
    at Dataverse_API_node.js:1
```

I have an **explore.html** page which calls the script **Dataverse_API_node.js**, which is itself dependent on the **require.js** file. My **Dataverse_API_node.js** script is supposed to display its output data on the **explore.html** page. However, I face the above error when I load the **explore.html** page.

Note that my **Dataverse_API_node.js** script runs independently without errors and displays the data in the command prompt when run through the **Node.js command prompt**.

There are the first few lines of the **Dataverse_API_node.js** script-

```
const https = require("https");

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

const demo_url = "https://demo.dataverse.org"

const actual_url = "https://demo.dataverse.org/dataverse/hbstest"

const search_uri = "/api/search"

const options = "?q=*&subtree=COSgak"
```

This is the part of **explore.html** where I'm calling the **Dataverse_API_node.js** script and supposed to display the data-

```
<p>
   <script src="Dataverse_API_node.js" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js">
        document.write(search_for_all("https://demo.dataverse.org", 0, 'file'));
   </script>
</p>
```

I'm new to Javascript and would really appreciate some help with this error. Please don't send me to **requirejs.org** as it doesn't really help.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. Just use browserify. Install browserify and then run the following command-

```
> browserify Dataverse_API_node.js > bundle.js
```

Browserify goes through all the '**require**' in your script and wraps it up in **bundle.js** and helps to run the node.js modules in the browser.

Just add the following script in your **.html** file-

```
<script type=text/javascript src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice job figuring this out.